# Python comprehension for random floats

Tags: python, random, list-comprehension

```
import random as rd
print([round(rd.random(), 3) for num in range(20)])
```

So this prints 20 random numbers shortened to 3 decimals.
How would I write the code so that it writes only random numbers higher than 0.4 but lower than or equal to 1?
Any combination of if statements I try yields an error.

Comment: Use `random.uniform(a, b)` instead of `random.random()` (*edit*: With `a, b = 0.4,1`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `random.uniform()`.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform).

```
import random as rd
print([round(rd.uniform(0.4, 1.0), 3) for num in range(20)])
```

Why do you round the values? You can also use random integers divided by `1000`:

```
import random as rd
print([rd.randint(401, 1000) / 1000 for num in range(20)])
```

The lowest you will get is `0.401` the highest is `1.0`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @FilipKramarić: If it solves your problem, you should accept this answer :)